# Botón dropdown (desplegable) hoverable

Tags: html, css

Tengo un desplegable que se abre cuando paso el ratón por encima hecho con HTML y CSS tal que así:

```css
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropbtn {
    height:30px;
    width:160px;
    background-color: #da291c;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #653734;
    min-width: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 5px 7px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
     <button class="dropbtn"><?php echo $lang['topbar_string_1']; ?></button>
 <div class="dropdown-content">
  <div class="row no-margin no-padding">
   <form>
    <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding ">
     <label class="white-text"><?php echo $lang['topbar_string_2']; ?></label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding ">
     <label class="white-text"><?php echo $lang['topbar_string_3']; ?></label>
     <input type="password" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding ">
     <button class="my-btn btn-primary" type="submit"><?php echo $lang['topbar_string_4']; ?></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding ">
     <a class="white-text" href="#"><?php echo $lang['topbar_string_5']; ?></a>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Pero me he topado con un problmea y esque aunque yo haga click en un input para escribir y saco el ratón fuera del contenido del dropdown, éste desaparece, y yo necesito que si yo le hago click dentro ya no desaparezca, que solo desaparezca si he pasado el ratón por encima y no he clickado nada.

Comment: puedes poner un evento onFocus para los input del dropmenu y que quede con display hasta que lo pierda y no tenga el raton encima

Comment: Solo con HTML y CSS no estoy seguro que puedas lograr el resultado que esperas, y necesitarías de javascript

Comment: Me temo que solo con CSS hasta que tengamos un selector de padres no vas poder hacerlo, como dice lois6b tendrás que hacerlo con un onfocus de javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilizando **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)** puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
var inputs = $(".dropdown-content input");

inputs.on("focus blur", function() {
  $(this).parents(".dropdown-content").toggleClass("open");
});
```

Seleccionamos los `inputs` dentro del contenido de tu `dropdown` y les asignamos dos eventos. `focus` cuando este enfocado el `input` y `blur` cuando pierda el enfoque.

Utilizamos la función `parents()` para recorrer el DOM pero con un selector para que llegue hasta `.dropdown-content` y después usamos `toggleClass` para agregar y remover la clase dependiendo si hay enfoque o no.

Clase:

```
.open {
  display: block;
}
```

---

### FRAGMENTO DE CÓDIGO:

```js
var inputs = $(".dropdown-content input");

inputs.on("focus blur", function() {
  $(this).parents(".dropdown-content").toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropbtn {
  height: 30px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #da291c;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #653734;
  min-width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 5px 7px;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">
    <?php echo $lang[ 'topbar_string_1']; ?>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div class="row no-margin no-padding">
      <form>
        <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding ">
          <label class="white-text">
            <?php echo $lang[ 'topbar_string_2']; ?>
          </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding ">
          <label class="white-text">
            <?php echo $lang[ 'topbar_string_3']; ?>
          </label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding ">
          <button class="my-btn btn-primary" type="submit">
            <?php echo $lang[ 'topbar_string_4']; ?>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding ">
          <a class="white-text" href="#">
            <?php echo $lang[ 'topbar_string_5']; ?>
          </a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No me funciona esto... Supongo que puede ser porque la clase dropdown content tiene un display:none... No sé si se podría poner que al hacer click dentro del contenido, aunque no sea dentro de un input funcionaría de alguna manera...

Comment: Asegúrate que tu clase `.open` este debajo de `.dropdown-content` en el archivo CSS. Si el problema persiste trata de utilizar `.open { display: block!important; }` y si así te funciona quiere decir que es un problema de specificity.

Comment: Si efectivamente es un problema de specificity lo que puedes hacer es en lugar de declarar únicamente `.open` utiliza  `.dropdown-content.open { display: block; }`.